# Function is printing Ascii equivalent rather then the integer as a string

Tags: assembly

Below is my attempt to write a function to convert an integer to string. I'm not sure if I'm using the push function correctly. I'm trying to divide the integer by 10 and adding 48h to the remainder and adding it to a stack. Then repeating the process until the whole integer is converted to a string. This function prints the string in Ascii but I want to print the exact integer in string representation. For example if the integer stored in variable answer is 75 then I want this function to print '75' as a string but it prints 'K'.

```
XOR eax, eax
    mov eax, [esi]
    mov cl, 10             ;move 10 to cl
    div cl                 ;divide by eax by 10
    add edx, 48h           ;add 48h to remainder
    push edx
    mov [edi], edx
    pop eax
    inc edi                ;increments the edi pointer
```

This is how I'm calling the function to convert the integer stored in answer to sting and print it.

```
lea esi, answer
call num2str
call PrintString
```

P.S. I'm using visual studio 2012 for compiling. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `div cl` is an 8-bit divide.  It divides ax by cl, putting the result in al and the remainder in ah -- edx is not affected.  You need to use `div ecx` to get a divide that divides the 64-bit value in the edx/eax register pair and puts the result in eax and the remainder in edx if you want your code to work -- which requires clearing the upper 24 bits of ecx and clearing edx as well:

```
;; eax = number to be converted to ASCII
;; edi = END of the buffer in which to store string
    xor ecx,ecx
    mov [edi], cl
    mov cl,10
loop:
    xor edx,edx
    div ecx
    add dl, 48h
    dec edi
    mov [edi], dl
    test eax,eax
    jnz loop
;; edi now points at the ASCII string
```